# Connected subsets of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I must determine whether the set $$\mathcal{U} = \{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\colon\,|\Re{(z)}|\ge 1\}$$ is connected. In my opinion this is not connected since if we take some point $z_{1} = -3+y_{1}i$ and another point $z_{2} = 4 + y_{2}i$ for any $y_{1},\,y_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ then we cannot find a polygonal line from $z_{1}$ to $z_{2}$. However in the solution it says this set is connected with no explanation, is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{U}$ can be written as the disjoint union of nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$
where
$$
A\equiv\left\{ z: \mathfrak{R}\left(z\right)\geq1\right\} 
$$
and
$$
B\equiv\left\{ z: \mathfrak{R}\left(z\right)\leq-1\right\} .
$$
Therefore, $\mathcal{U}$ is not connected.

Comment: Nonempty **closed** subsets.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro, it's just the same: $$\mathcal U=(\mathcal U\cap A)\cup(\mathcal U\cap B)\;$$ and both subsets are clopen in $\;\mathcal U\;$

Comment: @Timbuc This is clear enough. What I mean is that it is important to explain why this specific decomposition implies that the set is disconnected. Any set with more than 2 elements may be written as the disjoint union of two nonempty sets.